# Unknown Type: METHOD_DEF for Groovy Trait

Tags: groovy

I have the following trait:

```
trait DataSource{
    private File handle
    private List data

    def readFile(String target){
        try{
            handle = new File(target)
            data = handle.readLines()
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
            return false;
        }

    }

    def printLines(){
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
            println(data.get(i));
       }
    }

    def getData(){
         if(data != null){
             return data
         }else{
             return false;
         }
    }

    def getHandle(){
        if(handle != null){
            return handle
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
Error:(5, 5) Groovyc: Unknown type: METHOD_DEF at line: 5 column: 5. File: <SOMEFILE>
```

This syntax all looks correct to me, what am I doing wrong? Is this an issue with closures?

I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.1 CE on Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 0):

Since the syntax is correct I strongly assume that you have a too old Groovy version. Make IntelliJ use Groovy 2.3+ for this to work. I think the compiler treats `trait DataSource {...}" as method call with open block and fails over the method definition, since an open block cannot contain one.

Comment: I'm using Groovy 2.4.3

Comment: @Cayle this isn't using any of the fancy new 14.1 groovy compile options?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, I don't see anything in the settings pertaining to that.

Comment: Cayle, here https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-module-with-groovy-support.html you can find a guide about how to set the groovy version for new projects. For existing ones it should appear as library. Can you verify again that you are using Groovy 2.4.3? Can you try your code using the normal zip-distribution (or http://gvmtool.net/) and execute from the command line? Because if you are indeed using Groovy 2.4.3, then your install must be corrupted